# Avoiding Web Authentication Browser pop-up in a UWP App

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

Is it possible to avoid pop-ups in a UWP app when using WebAuthenticationBroker? I know that using WebAuthenticationBroker is not as secure as using the System Browser, but it's what we have to work with at this point. From my research and testing, there is no way to avoid popping-up the web authentication browser to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `AuthenticateSilentlyAsync` method of [WebAuthenticationBroker Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker#Methods).

> It starts the asynchronous authentication operation silently (no UI will be shown) with one input.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work. I still need the Web Authentication Broker. The broker will appear and allow the user to enter credentials on a federated endpoint. When the broker closes, an access token is returned from a successful authentication request. I think it's not reasonable to have the broker appear inline in a UWP app. Most users are also accustomed to seeing a pop-up when they are externally authenticated in a native app. Thanks though for the reply.